# Creating a due date formula based on case types with different working days

Tags: formula, date, case-object

I keep getting an error message saying there's missing ")" I have seen multiple formulas using mod functions and using 1962 as start off days, and honestly when I used those in Salesforce they were always off. So I tried this format for when I only had one due date default, 5 working days, and it worked. I haven't had a chance to test this one as I can't past the error, but I really am hoping it works, I need simplicity.

```
 CASE(Type,"Multiple queries", (WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),

    1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 12
    2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14
    3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14
    4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14
    5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14
    6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14
    7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 13)

"Legacy", (WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 40
   2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35
   3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35
   4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35
   5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35
   6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 39)

CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5,
   2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 6))
```

Sorry getting the formula to format was a struggle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
1, CASE(Type, 
        "Multiple queries", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 12,
        "Legacy", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 40,
         DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5
       ),
7, CASE(Type, 
        "Multiple queries", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 13,
        "Legacy", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 39,
         DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 6
       ),
CASE(Type, 
     "Multiple queries", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
     "Legacy", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
     DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7
    )
)
```

In this formula, I have first checked the weekday of the createddate and then based on the weekday I have checked the type and based on the type add the numbers of the day. like in 1st weekday and type Multiple queries then add 12 in createddate. same as if 1st weekday and the type is Legacy then add the 40 other wise if 1st weekday and no type match then add 5 in the createddate.
The same follows for the 7th weekday. for the other weekday's same value add that's why I have written it into the else part of the weekday case function.

Comment: Wow, that is very awesome Tushar! I will follow this format and try it out!

Comment: Tried it just now and it still doesn't seem to work. there's still a missing parenthesis

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the error showing?

Comment: Hi Tushar, got it resolved I forgot to put commas after the "result" part of the case functions. Then i needed to add Null at the very end to finish the formula off. thank you again, I kept your structure and added a few more types, it's the meatiest formula I've ever made! lol

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is missing commas.  Sometimes the syntax checker gets confused by missing commas and thinks you missed a closing parenthesis instead.  You are also missing a couple of inner CASE statements.  Also, CASE requires a default case at the end, even though in this case you don't need it since you cover all possible values of WEEKDAY.

Here is a version of your formula that compiles correctly for me.  I'm using `NULL` as a default value since it should never be returned and satisfies the field type of DATE.

```
CASE(Type,

"Multiple queries", (CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
    1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 12,
    2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
    3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
    4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
    5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
    6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14,
    7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 13,
    NULL)),

"Legacy", (CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 40,
   2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
   3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
   4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
   5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
   6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35,
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 39,
   NULL)),

/* Default */ CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5,
   2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7,
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 6,
   NULL))
```

And here is a simplified version that makes use of CASE()'s default case to remove a lot of duplication.

```
CASE(Type,

"Multiple queries", (CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
    1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 12,
    7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 13,
    /* Default */ DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 14)),

"Legacy", (CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 40,
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 39,
   /* Default */ DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 35)),

/* Default */ CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
   1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5,
   7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 6,
   /* Default */ DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7))
```

Comment: thank you! I added Null at the very end and put the correct commas and it worked! I am intrigued by this default option. I had so many more types that my Project manager wanted in the formula but it was too many characters for the formula field.